# innerHTML change font size with click of button for Ionic 5 or remove whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

i am experimenting of how to change font size of a variable at .html when the variable contain whitespace

```
at .ts page, the code to remove the whitespace

this.contents = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.product['description']);

at .html page, i displayed is as

<p id="p" class="p" [innerHtml]="contents"></p>
```

it works nice, but i had another function of changing font size dynamically when onclick button, everything inside [innerHtml] does not perform ChangeFontSize

example as follows for .html page

```
  <div class="container">
  <div">
  <ion-button (click)="ChangeFontSize('increase')"> A+ </ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="ChangeFontSize('decrease')"> A- </ion-button>
  </div>

  <h1 id="h"> {{product.title}}</h1>

  <p id="p">{{contents}}</p>

  <p id="p" class="p" [innerHtml]="contents"></p>

  </div>
```

div h1 changes dynamically
div p with {{contents}} changes dynamically showing whitespace br> &nbsp etc
and extra Safe value must use [property]=binding showing

[innerHtml] removed the whitespace but not able to changefontsize,

Hope anyone can enlightenment me what are the possible methods of removing

```
extra Safe value must use [property]=binding  and br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
```

or changing the font-size of [innerHtml]=“contents”

thank you very much

:bowing_man: :bowing_man: :bowing_man:

Answer (score 0):

In component ts

```
  contents = `This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps that are
  going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.`;

  fontSize = 10;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  increase() {
    this.fontSize++;
  }

  decrease() {
    this.fontSize--;
  }
```

In template:

```
 <p [style.font-size.px]="fontSize" class="p" [innerHtml]="contents"></p>
  <button type="button" (click)="increase()">Increase</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="decrease()">Decrease</button>
```

[Ionic Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7vswrk?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: hello,  thanks for your guidance,  i tried it and  i think the contents contained whitespace &&nbsp nsbp etc, so not able to change font size...., i experimented with other variables and it can change font size... is there a method to str.replace or something?  and not using innerHTML to display the variable and remove the whitesplace?

Comment: Share those content of which you are not able to change font-size

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help. I think you need global class like this.

Example

HTML

```
<div class="body fontSize16"> // Add font class to parent

<div class="container">
   <ion-button (click)="ChangeFontSize('increase')"> A+ </ion-button>
   <ion-button (click)="ChangeFontSize('decrease')"> A- </ion-button>
</div>

<h1 id="h"> {{product.title}}</h1>

<p id="p">{{contents}}</p>

<p id="p" class="p" [innerHtml]="contents"></p>
```

TS

```
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

private fontsizes = [12, 14, 16, 18];
private fontClass = 'fontSize';
private fontIndex = 0;
private renderer: Renderer2;

ngOnInit(): void {
   // I think you should set defualt fontsize.
}

constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
   this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
}

ChangeFontSize(type) {
   // Add more condition. Example array lenght or defualt value
   if (type === 'increase') {
     this.fontIndex + 1;
   } else if (type == 'decrease') {
     // pls add more condition. example check index of array
     this.fontIndex - 1;
   }
   this.removeClass(this.fontClass + this.fontsizes[this.fontIndex ]);
   this.addClass(this.fontClass + this.fontsizes[index]);
   this.fontIndex = index;
}

addClass(className: string) {
   this.renderer.addClass(document.body, className);
}

removeClass(className: string) {
   this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, className);
}
```

CSS

```
body.fontSize16 .p{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

SASS

```
body {
     &.fontSize16 {
        .p{ 
          font-size: 16px;
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: hello, thank you your guidance,  i would like to learn where can i put the SASS? inside IONIC 5 is it at global.scss?  currenting facing some issues with renderer 2 and renderer factory Property 'addClass' does not exist on type 'RendererFactory2'.  i give it another try